# Iterate through Paginated API Results in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I'm writing a function in Javascript that makes a fetch and receives results that are paginated (as expected, the results are long).

The results will contain a "next_page" which is the fetch home url for the next page of results.Ideally I would like to loop and constantly fetch until I reach the end of the results aka when "next_page" = null.

I can't seem to figure out how to loop through the results while next_page isn't null. What seems to happen is I get stuck in an infinite while loop.

Any suggestions welcome. I've provided pseudo code below.

```
while(next_page!=null){
   fetch(apiUrl)
  .then(res=>res.json())
   .then(data => {
    apiUrl=data["next_page]
   }
  if(apiUrl == null)
    {
      res.send(data)
      break;
    }
}
```

I was thinking the while loop would let me iterate until there was no next_page (aka when it's null). Seems like it's just infinite looping without ever hitting the fetch because the apiUrl doesn't get set to null.

Answer (score 4):

You can try below function, instead of while loop

```
// Initial API Call
fetchData('http://localhost/test1.php?page=1');

// Create the function for API Call 
function fetchData(apiUrl){ 
  fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      apiUrl = data['next_page'];
      // Check next API url is empty or not, if not empty call the above function 
      if(apiUrl != '' && apiUrl != null){
          fetchData(apiUrl);
      }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you're reading `data["next_page"]` to `apiUrl`, but then checking a different variable in the loop. Should be `while(apiUrl) { ...` instead.

Comment: try `console.log(data["next_page"])` to see what's there

Answer (score 0):

Following is loop fetch function, one can name it better though, this can be used in case there is not much logic at the backend side for next page.

```
const loopFetch = (previousResponse, fetchReq, limit, offset = 0) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    fetchReq(`&offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const allResponses = [...previousResponse, ...response];
        if (response.total === limit) {
          // above if condition states logic to check if there is next page
          // in my case it was checking limit and total records of response
          resolve(loopFetch(allResponses, fetchReq, limit, offset + limit)); // this will resolve previous promise with new loop promise and with all the previous data
        }
        else resolve(allResponses);
        // in case there is nothing more to fetch, else will resolve with all the responses.
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log({ err });
        resolve(previousResponse);
        // in case of error, resolving all the data that was fetched, can do more handling here (have'nt thought through here)
      });
  });
```

Calling the loop fetch API:

```
  const defaultAPILimit = 10;
  const headers = {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  };

  const fetchReq = (urlToAttach) =>
  fetch("http://dummyURL/?module=xyz" + urlToAttach, headers).then((response) => response.json());

  loopFetch([], fetchReq, defaultAPILimit)
    .then(() => {
      //do something after we have all the responses i.e. after pagination is completed.
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```